# Check when line is finish

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have a NSString which is a long coment. like in the bellow image . How can i check when the line is finish to begin a new one without separate the word and align under C: ?

[image]

Here is the code which i used for generate what you can see in image.This is used for generate content in pdf.

```
NSString *truckDesc=truckDescriptionArray[ii];
            truckDesc=[truckDesc uppercaseString];

            if (truckDesc.length>0) {
               string41=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"CAMION %d : %@ \r               C : %@", ii+1,truckName ,truckDesc];

            }
 [string41 drawInRect:textRect5 withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
```

Comment: May we have more explanation ? What's the component ? Some code ?

Comment: in just a second i will update my question

Comment: Where do yo display this text? Is it `UITextView` or `UILabel`? How big control you have on the text? Is it a pure `NSString` or it is a `NSTextContainer`?

Comment: is a NSString and it 's displayed in a rect  - textRect5 as you can see .